# How to format this Ajax Response Data?

Tags: ajax, json

I am new to ajax and managed to get cross domain ajax response data using a proxy. Here is the output

```
  {"error":"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\t\t
   You entered invalid Roll-Number, Please enter valid Roll Number.
  \r\n"}
```

How do I format it to get rid of everything except "You entered invalid Roll-Number, Please enter valid Roll Number"

EDIT: Is there some valid json function to format it or I do it through javascript?

**SOLUTION FOUND:**

Since it is valid JSON data I could use eval function to process it:

```
eval("var jsonDataFormatted =   ("+XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText+")");
console.log(jsonDataFormatted.error);
```

Comment: eval is always a bad idea, always try to avoid it. check out my post update for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be solved with javascript

Let's say you have your data in a variable called `data`

```
data = {"error":"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\t\t You entered invalid Roll-Number, Please enter valid Roll Number.\r\n"}
```

All you need to do is to trim the string so that you can remove spaces in the begining or in the end

```
data.error = data.error.trim();
```

### Update

If the solution you have found is `eval` then you better avoid it, this solution may help you

```
var jsonDataFormatted = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
console.log(jsonDataFormatted.error);
```

Comment: unfortunately, your code does not allow to get indexOf method

Comment: Firstly manage response format so that no need to do complex code for json data formatting.

Comment: The `while` loop is not actually required. You could just do `data.error = data.error.trim();`